# SELECT statement from two dataframes using RMySQL

Tags: string, r, rmysql

Consider two data frames, `dataFrame1` and `dataFrame2`:

- `dataFrame1` has N columns `(colmn1, ..., colmnN)`
- `dataFrame2` has 3 columns `(col1, col2, col3)`

Can I write a statement like:

```
Select colmn1, colmn2, ..., colmnN, col1, col2 from dataFrame1, dataFrame2
```

using `RMySQL`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want package `sqldf` instead.

Try this:

```
library("sqldf")
sqldf("select colmn1, colmn2, ..., colmnN, col1, col2 from dataFrame1, dataFrame2")
```

of course you must replace `...` with actual column names.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Cant write the actual column names because the number of columns may be different. I should avoid explicit column names in the query.

Comment: @stairway_2_7, You can use something like `"select a.*, b.col1, b.col2 from dataFrame1 a, dataFrame2 b"`.